# JQuery identifying element id through variable: multiple table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tables in each tab, as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5020/

The rows in each table has to be added and removed on button click.

I am replicating the row add function $("#anc_add2").click(function() {} and row remove function $("#anc_rem2").click(function(){ for each table with a different table id e.g. tabl1, tabl2, tabl3 etc.

The following function is important for adding and removing the rows in table:

```
 $('#tbl2 tr').last().after(rowdata);
 $('#tbl2 tr:last-child').remove();
```

How do I pass a TAB number as a parameter to a function so the table id can be generated with a variable and the variable can be used; something like this:

```
function onBtnClick(tabnumber) {
var tableid = "tabl" + tabnumber;
$(tableid tr).last().after(rowdata);
$(tableid tr:last-child').remove();
}
```

sample code is available at http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5020/

Comment: you are creating elements with same id. That is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `data-*` attributes to maintain custom data.

To use `selected-tab-index` in other methods, use it as `global-variable`.

Also note, use `classes` instead of `id` attributes while dealing with dynamic elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var global = 1;
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    global = $(this).data('id');
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
  $(".anc_add").click(function() {
    var rowdata = '<tr > <td> <input size="5" type="text"> </td>';
    rowdata += '<td> <input  size="5"  type="text"> </td> </tr>';
    $('#tbl' + global + ' tr').last().after(rowdata);
  });

  $(".anc_rem").click(function() {
    if ($('#tbl' + global + ' tr').size() > 1) {
      $('#tbl' + global + ' tr:last-child').remove();
    } else {
      alert('One row should be present in table');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.tabs-menu {
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.tabs-menu li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
}
.tabs-menu li.current {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}
.tabs-menu li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs-menu .current a {
  color: #2e7da3;
}
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto;
}
.tab-content {
  width: 660px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
#tab-1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1" data-id='1'>Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-id='2'>Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3" data-id='3'>Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4" data-id='4'>Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">

      <!-- Add row and Delete buttons -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='anc_add'>Add Row</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='anc_rem'>Remove Row</a>

      <!-- Table 1 in TAB 1 -->

      <table class="table text-center table-bordered table-striped volumes tabcenter" style="align:center; margin:15px; width:40%" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><b>Node</b> 
            </th>
            <th><b>Data</b> 
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl1">

          <tr>
            <td>
              <input size="5" type="text" id="Node_TR11">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input size="5" type="text" id="Data_TR11">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <!-- End of Tab 1 -->
    <!-- Tab 2 Start -->
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      <!-- Add row and Delete buttons for TAB2 -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='anc_add'>Add Row</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='anc_rem'>Remove Row</a>
      <!-- Table 2 in TAB 2 -->

      <table class="table text-center table-bordered table-striped volumes tabcenter" style="align:center; margin:15px; width:40%" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><b>Node</b> 
            </th>
            <th><b>Data</b> 
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl2">

          <tr>
            <td>
              <input size="5" type="text" id="Node_TR21">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input size="5" type="text" id="Data_TR21">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>



    </div>

    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      <p>TAB 3: Hello World !</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      <p>TAB 4: Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$(this).data('id')` could be used to access `data-id`

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5030/)

Comment: I want to know how to use the variable as element id here $('#tbl2 tr').last().after(rowdata);  how to replace #tabl2 or #tabl1 as variable . i tried using a var tableid = "tabl" + id.toString(); and use as $(tableid tr).last().after(rowdata); it is not working !!

Comment: First of all, ID must be unique..You need to use `classes` as events attached using `id` selector will be attached to the first element having specified id. Use `global` variable and store the value of the selected tab in global variable.. Now you can use it in other functions... Try this out!

Comment: tried with  $('#tbl+tabnum tr').last().after(rowdata); not working! its not calling the function.  two 'Add Row' links with same   id='anc_add. its working if i use only one 'Add Row' in one TAB http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/5036/

Comment: Did you check the fiddle I have provided ? You are still dealing with the `id` attributes.. Use `classes`.. Also go through the answer I have updated...

Comment: just looked into it, i am looking for this !! $('#tbl' + global + ' tr').last().after(rowdata); double quotes, single quotes confused me while concat !.  thanks.

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

You need this html instead of yours:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anc_add">Add Row</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anc_rem">Remove Row</a>
```

Never duplicate `id`s in your html, since it makes your html work in a sub-par manner. Then you need functions, like this:

```
function addRow(context) {
    //add a row using the context object
}

function remRow(context) {
    //remove a row using the context object
}

function getContext(referrer) {
    return referrer.find("table");
}

$(function() {
    $(".anc_add").click(function () {
        addRow(getContext($(this).parent()));
    });

    $(.anc_rem).click(function() {
        remRow(getContext($(this).parent()));
    });
});
```

By the way, if you can not change your structure and you have multiple `id`s having the value of `anc_add`, then you can select them with the property selector:

```
$("[id=anc_add]")
```

as

```
$("#anc_add")
```

will stop when the first element was found, as `id` is assumed to be unique.